# Trying to assign a path to the ArgumentParser

Tags: python

I'm trying to access to the "resources" folder with the ArgumentParser.
This code and the "resources" folder are in the same folder...

Just to try to run the code, I've put a print function in the predict function. However this error occurs:

```
predict.py: error: the following arguments are required: resources_path
```

How can I fix it?

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("resources_path", help='/resources')

    return parser.parse_args()


def predict(resources_path):

    print(resources_path)

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parse_args()
    predict(args.resources_path)
```

Comment: How are you calling it?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from your error message that you are trying to call your program like this:

```
python predict.py
```

The argument parser by default gets the arguments from `sys.argv`, i.e. the command line. You'll have to pass it yourself like this:

```
python predict.py resources
```

It's possible that you want the resources argument to default to `./resources` if you don't pass anything. (And I further assume you want `./resources`, not `/resources`.) There's a keyword argument for that:

```
....
parser.add_argument('resources_path', default='./resources')
...
```

Comment: Thank you! My error was that i was not running the program through the terminal, but compiling it directly from the editor